# How to map from model to field using a different name

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, mapping, field

I've got a model which has a field with a name property, for example:

```
fields: [{
        name: 'first',
        type: 'string'
    }]
```

Now I've got a display field to show this field from the model, but I cant name it the same as in the model, which would look like this:

```
 {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      name: 'first'
 }
```

Instead, I need the field to be named something like whats shown below (which is different from the name given in the model)

```
     {
          xtype: 'displayfield',
          name: 'firstName'
     }
```

Now my question is, how can I do this keeping the name in the model and using a different name for the field?

I've done some research and found the 'mapping' property in [Ext.data.field](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.Field.html):

```
fields: [{
        name: 'first',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'firstName'
    }]
```

But you need to give the nameProperty config the value 'mapping' [in the writer of the proxy](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.writer.Json.html), and I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for because I haven't managed to make it work (and I think the writer is for sending data back to the server).
So, can I specify the nameProperty somewhere else? Am I on the right path? Is there any other solution available?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new *calculated* property in your model:

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'firstName',
    calculate: function() {
      return this.get('first');
    }
  }],
});
```

**Note** this code is valid for ExtJS version 5 and above.

**Using `mapping` property**

In case you need to receive a field with different name from server, you can use `mapping` property. For instance, if you receive the following JSON from server:

```
[{
  first_name: 'Dimitri',
  last_name: 'Kurashvili'
}]
```

Then in model:

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'firstName',
    mapping: 'first_name'
  }, {
    name: 'lastName',
    mapping: 'last_name'
  }],
});
```

Comment: How could this be mapped into the field?

Comment: Alright! I see it much clearer now, thank you! When would this calculate function be called? - Also, do you know if the mapping thing can be done? Or its something completely different (seems like a cleaner approach)

Comment: *Calculated* field is used just like usual field. To my knowledge `mapping` is related to reader of the model. For example, if you receive data via JSON, and the field `first` is encoded into `FIRST` field, you can define it in `mapping` attribute.

Comment: `calculated` is available from version 5 only, isn't it? An answer for version 4 is needed.

Comment: @DrakeEnterpriseSystems Indeed! that is true, I believe we haven't updated to v. 5 yet. @ dimakura Thankyou! So I assume calculate is called automatically when assigning the name value to the field? - Also, that sounds like my case, could you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: Oh, I probably missed you working on version below 5. What example do you mean?

Comment: I mean the "if you receive data via JSON, and the field first is encoded into FIRST field, you can define it in mapping attribute", because I am indeed receiving data via JSON, and I receive "first" but need to map it to "firstName". Thankyou!

Comment: @dimakura Alright! Is that all that is needed? I mean, do I need to specify  the mapping somewhere? Like nameProperty: 'mapping' or something like that?